# Google maps for event reporting

Tags: events, google-maps, reporting

Is it possible to use Google maps for event reporting?

Here's what I want to do: a running program send some data to google server to update the "objects" on a map. The objects needs to change color and popup information.
Then, an user (preferably with login and password) view the google map updated in real time with the information sent by the program above.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that. Here is an example: http://www.phillywatersheds.org/what_were_doing/documents_and_data/live_data/csocast

This system takes data from a monitoring network, processes it and updates the markers on the map depending on the values of the data.

The only problem with your scenario is that the map must be publicly-accessible to use the Google Maps API. Otherwise, you have to pay to use the [Google Maps Premier License](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html).